# How can I use a reverse proxy on a server hosting a website?

Tags: linux, reverse-proxy, apache-2.4

I have a server hosting a website that I am trying to additionally function as a reverse proxy server. The purpose is to obfuscate the url of an application from http://www.acme.bar.com:8760/Application to loremipsum.bar.com.

I have an alias for loremipsum.bar.com pointed at the reverse proxy/web host with the following virtualhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/public
    <Directory /var/www/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
    </Directory>
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPass / http://www.acme.bar.com:8760/Application
    ProxyPassReverse / http://www.acme.bar.com:8760/Application
    ServerName loremipsum.bar.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Unfortunately, now visiting loremipsum.bar.com gives ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS and times out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using something like Fiddler (or a browser's developer tool network inspector with persisting of requests turned on) to watch what redirects are being sent that's causing the redirect loop.  You could also try adding a slash at the end of your proxy URLs just in case that makes a difference - that's how I've set it up and how the example on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse has it.